# Loading the same ant build file for each module in a maven multi-module project?

Tags: maven, ant

I have a large, multi-module maven project. I want to move some generated files around after the **compile** phase, so I have added the following plugin to the parent `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>move-stuff</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          ... lots of ant stuff here ...
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This works, but there's a lot of ant task stuff between the `target` elements, which should rightly move into an ant `build.xml` file. The problem is that I would need to specify the location of the `build.xml` file in the plugin:

```
<configuration>
  <ant antfile="build.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

But the location of this file cannot be specified in such a way that it can be loaded by both the parent `pom.xml` and the `pom.xml` in each child module. One cannot use `${project.basedir}/build.xml` for example because that gives a result relative to each module, not relative to the top-level project directory. Similarly, one cannot use `../build.xml` because that will work only with child modules and not with the parent module.

Is there a way to specify an antfile location in the `maven-antrun-plugin` that will work for every module in my project? Or am I stuck with leaving lots of ant code in my `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Is there a way you can avoid the parent needing to do any ant stuff? Alternately, how about separating to two ant files, the tasks done by parent and children poms?

Comment: I can separate by adding the `maven-antrun-plugin` to each child module, pointing back to a common location (e.g. _../build/xml_) although that means a lot of replication, as well as introducing an ugly external dependency. Hoping to avoid both, but it may be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

One way to this is to use the `user.dir` property:

```
    <target>
      <ant antfile="${user.dir}/build.xml"/>
    </target>
```

Of course, this only works when you trigger your build from the root project.